# how to use regex in jquery instead of match function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used match function to get if there is "http:ca" present in url if present "CA".If there is "http:fr" present in url if present "fr". But some some told me that using regex it is easy to do that. Can you please tell me how can I achieve same functionality using regex.

here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/PWEAR/15/

```
function CheckUrl(url){
    //alert(url);
    var str=url;
    var res = str.match(/http:\\ca/g);
      if(res=="http:\\ca")
          return "ca";

    var res=str.match(/http:\\fr/g)
    if(res=="http:\\fr")
       return "fr";
    else
        return "no fr and ca";


}
```

Comment: Please read documentation on [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: The `match()` function **is** using regular expressions.

Comment: `/http:\\ca/g` is the regex..

Comment: `http:\\ VS http://`?

Comment: ok it mean it is already a regex

Comment: For static strings, I'd just use `str.indexOf('http://ca') != -1`

Answer (score 0):

How about making it a little more dynamic...

```
var rx = new RegExp('http://(ca|fr)');
var result = rx.exec(url);
return result && result[1] || 'no fr or ca';
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/PWEAR/20/